# Interact with the OS hosting an Ethereum node

Tags: bash, call, ethereum, solidity

Is there a way to make calls to the system (like calling traceroute) using Solidity or maybe Web3?  If that's not a clear question, I'm imagining executing a contract and having that contract perform system commands based on the contract.

I can't think of a way to to this with Embark, which I've been learning, so I'm thinking that I'll just need to send http requests to a python backend where I'll make system calls.  Can anyone think of a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no direct way to get access to file system from Solidity. You are limited to VM commands. But you can use [Oraclize](http://oraclize.it) to do HTTP requests to your server that will do the job: [code examples](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/tree/master/solidity) as well as [documentation](http://docs.oraclize.it). And [here](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/blob/master/solidity/KrakenPriceTicker.sol#L29) is an example of HTTP request from Solidity.